# Conditioning on multiple dataframes and writing in the new value

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes with same columns. For example:

```
       Data1               Data2                       Data3
   Tweet  Score      Tweet     Score              Tweet    Score
1   cnk     3         cnk        -5                cnk      -2
2   found   2         dragon      5                random    7
3   random  4         breath      2
4   china  -7         random      3
5   blue    1         red         2
```

I merged Data1 and Data2 and created Data3, then grouped by tweet and transformed by count. Then i removed words with 1 count so Data3 would have only words that exist in both Data1 and Data2. Then I had Data3 grouped by sum.

I need to add Data3 a new column called Sentiment. To set value for each word in Data3, i would need to check the same words in Data1 and Data2 To see;

1. If both values are positive
2. If one value is positive and the othes is negative
3. If both valuse are negative

Depending on the output of conditions, i would assign an integer to Sentiment. Any ides how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_sentiment(word, df1, df2):
    # Either one (or both) values are not found.
    if df1[df1['Tweet'] == word].empty or df2[df2['Tweet'] == word].empty:
        return 'value not found either in df1 or df2'

    # Both values are positive
    if int(df1[df1["Tweet"] == word]['Score']) > 0 and int(df2[df2["Tweet"] == word]['Score']) > 0:
        return 1

    # Both values are negative
    if int(df1[df1["Tweet"] == word]['Score']) < 0 and int(df2[df2["Tweet"] == word]['Score']) < 0:
        return -1

    # remaining case
    return 0


data_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Tweet': ['cnk', 'found', 'random', 'china', 'blue'],
                       'Score': [3, 2, 4, -7, 1]})

data_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Tweet': ['cnk', 'dragon', 'breath', 'random', 'red'],
                       'Score': [-5, 5, 2, 3, 2]})

data_3 = pd.DataFrame({'Tweet': ['cnk', 'random'],
                       'Score': [-2, 7]})

data_3['sentiment'] = data_3['Tweet'].apply(get_sentiment, df1=data_1, df2=data_2)

print(data_3)
    Tweet  Score  sentiment
0     cnk     -2          0
1  random      7          1
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. This works really well. I am new to python and i wasn't sure how to use if else cases with dataframes. Teşekkürler!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you only want to perform the operation for words appearing on both datasets only. I would merge both dataframes and then create a column that encodes the conditions you want.

```py
data3 = data1.merge(data2, on="Tweet", suffixes=["_1", "_2"]

# generate the "Score" as sum of both scores
data3["Score"] = data3["Score_1"] + data3["Score_2"]

# add a column "Sentiment" with encapsulates the desired logic:
#  0 means both scores are negative
#  1 means both scores are opposite sign
#  2 means both scores are non-negative (>=0)
data3["Sentiment"] = (data3["Score_1"] >= 0).astype(int) + (data3["Score_2"] >= 0).astype(int)
```

This would be the resulting dataframe:

```py
       Tweet  Score_1  Score_2  Score  Sentiment
0        cnk        3       -5     -2          1
1     random        4        3      7          2
```

You can substract 1 if you want the sentiment to range from -1 to 1. Also, you can remove `Score_1` and `Score_2` columns if they are not needed anymore.

Comment: This also seems to work. It looks simpler but it is harder to understand. Thank you too for taking the time to answer kind sir.